# How to stub return value of a useHook in cypress (web browser)?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

My react app is like this

```
import { useConfig } from "@external/lib";

const App = () => {
  // e.g. platformName == a, platformName == b, platformName == c
  const { platformName } = useConfig();

  return <Main platformName={platformName}></Main>;
};
```

How do I stub the return value of `useConfig` in **cypress**?

e.g.

test case 1
useConfig return 'a'

test case 2
useConfig return 'b'

etc..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to import an entire module and then just stub one function out of it, defining what the stub should return.

```js
import * as externalLib from '@external/lib';

cy.stub(externalLib, "useConfig").returns({ platformName: 'a' });
cy.stub(externalLib, "useConfig").returns({ platformName: 'b' });
```